# (benchmark) endless loop without freezing the thread

Tags: c#, infinite-loop

I'm writing a tiny c# program which hashes hashes. I would like it to do 2 things (somewhat like benchmarks):

```
hash = md5.ComputeHash(hash);
tell me how many times per second it can do this.
```

At the moment I have a timer with an OnTimedEvent to keep track of how many hashes come through per second and an infinite while(true) loop to keep the hashing going. Offcourse my program and timer freeze as soon as the hashing starts.

What is the proper way to do this? How can I keep on hashing (and having output) without freezing?

Thanks in advance!

Maarten

At this point everything is quiete linear except the timer.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int count;
    private MD5 md5;
    private byte[] hash;
    private bool Calculate = false;
    private System.Timers.Timer timer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        count = 0;
        PrepareFirstHash(); 
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000); 
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
    private void PrepareFirstHash()
    {
        md5 = MD5.Create();
        byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("start");
        hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
    }
    private void DoCalc()
    {
        hash = md5.ComputeHash(hash);
        count++;
    }
    private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetText(count.ToString());
        count = 0;
    }

    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (this.label1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.label1.Text = text;
        }
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Calculate = true;
        while (Calculate){
            DoCalc();
        }
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Calculate = false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Sounds like a job for `BackgroundWorker`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: If you're just timing a single method, why not use a console app and `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run everything on the UI thread now, so the BackgroundWorker option isn't so bad.

You really have to dive in multithreaded programming, though following can give a headstart:
http://codesamplez.com/programming/multithreaded-programming-c-sharp